# How to write queue base code using PL/SQL not using Oracle queue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, message-queue

I would like to write queue base code to process assign thread and process for multi threaded application. I don't want to use Oracle provided queue. I have table where it has rows by application's symbol. I would want to write generic process to read this table and process one row by assigning as thread. I would also like to know how to dequeue and enqueue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I dont want to use ORACLE provided queue" Reinventing the wheel? nice move =)

Comment: if ur not even sure where to begin, u think maybe this is a bad idea to roll ur own AQ?

Answer (score 4):

To do it effectively without introducing serialization issues, you'd need to be on Oracle 11g, which introduced the `SKIP LOCKED` clause to the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement.

However, as Vincent Malgrat mentioned, you're reinventing the wheel - and that's just not a good idea.